# Merging content of all columns of one row together in whole file (one csv file)

Tags: python, csv, merge

I have a huge problem with my code and I hope someone can help out here. I had to extract a specific element out of xml files, which lay in multiple subdirectories. I wrote a script to go though all folders and subdirectories to get to the xml files and extract that one element and save it in a separate file. I managed to do that, but the text from the xml-element is somehow distributed across multiple cells in one row. However I need to have one text in one cell in a row like this:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Text |  |  |  |

and not like it is now:

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | e | x | t |

The code looks like this:

```
import os

import csv

import itertools

import pandas as pd

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

path = "D:/..."

file = open('out.csv', 'w')

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for filename in files:
        if not filename.endswith(".xml"): continue
        if filename.endswith(".xml"):
            fullname = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
            tree = ET.parse(fullname)
            print (tree)
            root = tree.getroot()
            for row in root.iter('p'):
                file.write(row.text + ",")
            file.write("\n")
```

How do I get to my desired result? Hope that someone can help out!

---

Comment: Why not just fix the XSLT?

Comment: Is the comma in `file.write(row.text + ",")` being interpreted as a new item in a .csv file?

Comment: @Neil  what´s the XSLT? I should mention that I´m a noop in programming...

Comment: @rossum I tried it without the "," and got the same result

Comment: That comma is going somewhere.  It doesn't show up in your current output, just the individual letters, not the commas.

Comment: When you said you extracted the data from XML, I assumed you used XSLT (the XML programming language), to do so.  It sounds like you didn't.